# Warming IP through Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to do IP Warming while using Lists in Marketing Cloud. One of the best recommendations is to send just to those subscirbers who have been more engaged. However, the list model is not as flexible as Data Extensions and I find confusing the process of filtering the lists by engagement.

Anyone has been through the same scenario?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use reporting and add subscribers based on the data to specific lists (maybe you have engagement data in your internal data warehouse that you could use?)
2. List model often means = prepare your data "locally/outside SFMC" (spreadsheet, DBMS exports, custom reporting => import to a list)
3. Check overall bounce stats for every job (tracking). Anything over 10% is quite bad - "Blocked bounce type" means your emails are getting blocked due to the bad reputation (ISP)
4. Be very careful on the quantity of emails that you're intending to send in each week - you should slowly increase the volume of sends over time... for instance : 20k 1st week, 40k 2nd week and so on... details below (point 4)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_address_warming.htm&type=5